# How general cost function for $p = \log n$ is the $k$-center cost function?

Tags: clustering

The $k$-clustering problem is defined as follows: Given a set $C$ of clients and a set $L$ of facility locations defined over a distance metric $d$. Open a set $F$ of $k$ facility in $L$ such that the total cost of assigning the clients to their closest facilities is minimized, i.e.,

$$\text{minimize} \quad \Phi_{p}(F) \equiv \left( \sum_{j = 1}^{|C|} \, d(j,F)^{p} \right)^{1/p}, \quad \quad \text{where } d(j,F) = \min_{f \in F} \big\{ d(j,f) \big\}$$

For the $k$-median problem $p = 1$; for the $k$-means problem $p = 2$; and for the $k$-center problem $p = \infty$. I agree with all these definitions.

However, in the abstract of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2554.pdf) paper, the authors say that a $O(p)$-approximation for the $k$-clustering problem gives $O(\log n)$ approximation for the $k$-center problem. I could not understand this. On page 8, they also state the following statement:

> The
> implication for $k$-center follows from the fact that for vectors of length $n$, the norm $\|.\|_{\infty}$ is within a
> constant factor of the norm $\|.\|_{\log n}$, and hence $\max_{j \in C} d(j, F)$ is within a constant factor of $\Phi_{\log n}(F)$.

I could not prove this fact. Can somebody please provide some hint/reference for the same? Thank You.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but isn't the $p$-norm statement just that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}\leq \|\mathbf{x}\|_{\log n}\leq (n\|\mathbf{x}\|^{\log n}_{\infty})^{1/\log n}\leq e\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\infty}$. The abstract says they give a $O(p)$ approximation for the $\ell_p$ norm for any $p$, which is degenerate for $p=\infty$, but this computation shows you can use it for $p=\log n$ to get a $O(\log n)$ approximation for the $k$-center problem.

Comment: @J.G Yup. You are absolutely right! I completely missed that. It answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: glad to have helped!